# Accessing object values within array within object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, openweathermap

I'm trying to process data from the OpenWeather API for multiple cities. This is what the data looks like:

```
{
"cnt":20,
"list":[
    {
    "coord":{"lon":-99.13,"lat":19.43},
    "sys":{"country":"MX","timezone":-18000,"sunrise":1591012665,"sunset":1591060290},
    "weather":[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02d"}],
    "main":{"temp":12.88,"feels_like":11.84,"temp_min":12.78,"temp_max":13,"pressure":1027,"humidity":82},
    "visibility":8047,
    "wind":{"speed":1.5,"deg":60},
    "clouds":{"all":20},
    "dt":1591013691,
    "id":3530597,
    "name":"Mexico City"},
    {...next cities...}
    ]
}
```

I'm fine with everything, except the weather part(3rd line). I want to assign each value to a separate variable like so:

```
weatherid = 801
main = "Clouds"
description = "few clouds"
```

I've tried stuff around the lines of

```
main = citydata.list[i].weather.main;       (doesn't work)
main = citydata.list[i].weather.main();     (doesn't work)
main = Object.values(citydata.list[i].weather);
```

and quite a few things in between.

(Well, the last one kinda does something but I don't end up with something different, and when I try and get the values it's always "undefined")

So, what's the simplest way of accessing that data and storing each part of it in its own variable. 
Or even just converting the contents of "main" into an array (I'm assuming those questions overlap)

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `citydata.list[i].weather[0].main` as weather var, is an array not json!( An array containing json)

Comment: Thanks - that did it! Thank you! Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
 const data =  JSON.parse(req.data);
 const main = data.list[0].weather.main
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting an error message on JSON.parse (I'm running this in a local environment, if that makes a difference).

Comment: Post here the error please?

Comment: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript.php take a look at this ref

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.